# Is it possible to "lock out" or disable other Android applications?

Tags: android

I was wondering if there are any APIs within the Android SDK that allow an app to lock out (disable access to) other apps on your android phone.

would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction, if such an API exists.

Note: I DO NOT intend to use this for malicious purposes

Comment: If only there was a way to permanently disable all the default-installed Samsung apps :'(

Comment: I am more interested in disabling specific 3rd party apps

Comment: If you go to settings, you see a disable button. If thats what u want to achieve then it can be done using package manager. (Though i dont remember if you need root access or not for that operation)

Comment: Thank you, will look into this option

Comment: if you need sample, you can look into cyanogen trebuchet launcher source code. they do the same thing named as protected app